# Server Error ApolloError: Response not successful: Received status code 401

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I have a problem with start my NextJS project.
When I started on my computer with using command "npm run dev" everything it works correctly.
I have a problem in the moment when I can use for example Vercel or when I clone git repository on another computer on school. I don't know what the problem is, but maybe in enviroment who is cannot been on github repository because he is written in gitignore or something what i have in gitignore makes this problem.

This is my github repository. https://github.com/ThomasTomanec/portfolio-website

---

Server Error
ApolloError: Response not successful: Received status code 401

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
new ApolloError
file:///C:/Users/student/Desktop/Nov%C3%A1%20slo%C5%BEka/portfolio-website/node_modules/@apollo/client/errors/errors.cjs (33:28)

file:///C:/Users/student/Desktop/Nov%C3%A1%20slo%C5%BEka/portfolio-website/node_modules/@apollo/client/core/core.cjs (1994:78)
both
file:///C:/Users/student/Desktop/Nov%C3%A1%20slo%C5%BEka/portfolio-website/node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/utilities.cjs (1269:31)

file:///C:/Users/student/Desktop/Nov%C3%A1%20slo%C5%BEka/portfolio-website/node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/utilities.cjs (1260:72)
new Promise

Object.then
file:///C:/Users/student/Desktop/Nov%C3%A1%20slo%C5%BEka/portfolio-website/node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/utilities.cjs (1260:24)
Object.error
file:///C:/Users/student/Desktop/Nov%C3%A1%20slo%C5%BEka/portfolio-website/node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/utilities.cjs (1271:49)
notifySubscription
file:///C:/Users/student/Desktop/Nov%C3%A1%20slo%C5%BEka/portfolio-website/node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js (140:18)
onNotify
file:///C:/Users/student/Desktop/Nov%C3%A1%20slo%C5%BEka/portfolio-website/node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js (179:3)
SubscriptionObserver.error
file:///C:/Users/student/Desktop/Nov%C3%A1%20slo%C5%BEka/portfolio-website/node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js (240:7)

file:///C:/Users/student/Desktop/Nov%C3%A1%20slo%C5%BEka/portfolio-website/node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/utilities.cjs (1253:68)
Array.forEach

iterateObserversSafely
file:///C:/Users/student/Desktop/Nov%C3%A1%20slo%C5%BEka/portfolio-website/node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/utilities.cjs (1253:25)
Object.error
file:///C:/Users/student/Desktop/Nov%C3%A1%20slo%C5%BEka/portfolio-website/node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/utilities.cjs (1333:21)
notifySubscription
file:///C:/Users/student/Desktop/Nov%C3%A1%20slo%C5%BEka/portfolio-website/node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js (140:18)

idksdaadsasdasdsaddsasadsda

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is because of the environment variable. You have to add this variable in the computer, which builds the project - if you build the project with GitHub Actions, you have to provide the environment variable there. If it is somewhere else, I am pretty sure there is a way to add the environment variable.

Comment: I have an ".env.local" file on my computer in my project. This file is not in github, but at the same time it contains a key, a token to access the api of my github account. Therefore, I would need to upload this file to git but encrypted, or advise how to add the vercel environment to the project. When I want to add enviroment to vercel, it wants filename and value. I don't know what value means, what they want me to enter from vercel and where I should find it.

Answer (score 0):

I have an ".env.local" file on my computer in my project. This file is not in github, but at the same time it contains a key, a token to access the api of my github account. Therefore, I would need to upload this file to git but encrypted, or advise how to add the vercel environment to the project. When I want to add enviroment to vercel, it wants filename and value. I don't know what value means, what they want me to enter from vercel and where I should find it.

Comment: If you are adding more context to your question then it is best to update your original question with that information since this is not a valid answer to your issue